# Let A be a countable set, and let $f : A \to B$ be a function. Prove that $f(A)$ is at most countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A$ be a countable set, and let $f : A \to B$ be a function. Prove that $f(A)$ is at most countable.

Therefore $A$ is bijective with positive integers.

Since the function is defined, it is clear that every elements in $A$ will not map to a different elements in $B$, i.e., for every  $a\in A$ there exists a unique $b\in B$. So we don't care much whether the function is bijective or whatever.

I also know that $f(A)$ is at most countable if it is either finite or countable.

I think that $f(A)$ if proved as finite, should be a key to this proof, and to show if it is finite we may need to show something on the line that $|f(A)| < |A|$.

I don't know how all these pieces fit together to construct a proof. Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: A set $A$ is just written $A$, not $\{A\}$. The notation $\{A\}$ indicates a singleton set whose unique element is the set $A$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that functions map countable sets to countable sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163912/prove-that-functions-map-countable-sets-to-countable-sets)

Comment: No, I didn't understand the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints.

You can assume without loss of generality, that $A=\mathbb{N}$ and $f(A)=B$. (Details left to you.)

To show that $B$ is at most countable, it suffices to construct an injective function from $B$ to $\mathbb{N}$. Define $g: B\to \mathbb{N}$ such that $g(x)=\min\{n\in\mathbb{N}:f(n)=x\}$. Show that this is a well-defined injective function.

Comment: Thank you. Got it!